# can use v2ray configuration for V2box?

Tags: server, vpn, proxy

i have a [vpn v2ray](https://github.com/v2rayng-vpn/v2rayng) configuration of GitHub i want to know can i use it in V2BOX app?

Comment: Are you even using Ubuntu? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].